# Why does the BackgroundWorker not call the RunWorkerCompleted on the right thread in this unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The whole point of the backgroundWorker is to update the UI after a time-consuming task. The component **works as advertised** in my WPF app.

However in my test, the callback is not invoked on the calling thread.

```
[Test]
public void TestCallbackIsInvokedOnClientThread()
{

     var clientId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
     int callbackThreadId = -1;
     var manualEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

     var someUIControl = new TextBox();
     var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

     bw.DoWork += (s,e) => e.Result = 5 ; // worker thread

     bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                  {
                                      try
                                      {
                                          callbackThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                                          //someUIControl.Text = callbackThreadId.ToString();
                                          manualEvent.Set();
                                      }
                                      catch (System.Exception ex)
                                      {
                                          Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                                      }
                                  };
     bw.RunWorkerAsync();

     if (!manualEvent.Wait(5000))
         Assert.Fail("no callback");
     Assert.AreEqual(clientId, callbackThreadId);
 }
```

Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<15>. Actual:<10>. callback not invoked on client Thread

What am I missing ?

In the Unit Test I see behavior like

```
------ Run test started ------
MainThread Id =21
Worker Thread Id =9
Callback Thread Id =9
```

In the Wpf App, this would be

```
MainThread Id =1
Worker Thread Id =14
Callback Thread Id =1
```

**Update:**
With Justin's answer, made the following changes and now the test passes

- Before creating the BackgroundWorker
  `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(control.Dispatcher));`
- Instead of using a event for signalling between the threads, simulate a message pump

.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    control.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                          new Action(delegate { }));
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the id of the backgroundworker thread? Maybe it's not called on that one either.

Comment: @Tudor - updated post with more info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behavior is different dues to the different contexts that you are running under.

When you call bw.RunWorkerAsync(), the SynchronizationContext is captured.  This is used to dispatch out the RunWorkerCompleted call.

Under WPF it will use DispatcherSynchronizationContext which will marshall the completed call back to the UI thread.  Under the test, this marshalling is unnecessary so it remains on the background worker thread.

Comment: This seems to the missing piece - SynchronizationContext.Current is null in the unit test.

Answer (score 3):

I belive that the calling thread must support messagepumping (mean, being STA apartment and having an associated Dispatcher) so the background worker can post the callback. If it does not, the background worker has no option but execute the callback in its own thread. If you want to test it, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381967/show-wpf-window-from-test-unit/13382721#13382721).

Comment: Yes, how could it possibly hijack a thread that is doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem in my code where the user closing a window caused a save, that in turn used a BackgroundWorker to update the home window and it did not run the RunWorkerCompleted because the thread that started the BackgroundWorker had terminated when the window closed.

I had to change the closing window's save run in the home window's context so that after the BackgroundWorker completed, it had a thread to return to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using Windows Forms and controls don't have a **Dispatcher** property (see the answer in [no definition for dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172207/1849495)).

Gishu's solution works as well if we use **Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher** instead of the one in the control.

On test initialisation:

```
// I am using a field Dispatcher _dispatcher
_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

And then when waiting for the background task to be completed:

```
_dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
Thread.Sleep(50);
```