# no definition for dispatcher

Tags: c#, winforms, dispatcher

I'm getting the error

> 'socketServer.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'socketServer.Form1' could be found

From

```
private void tbAux_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {
        textBox.Text = tbAux.Text;
    }
    );
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `Dispatcher` class is part of the namespace `System.Windows.Threading`, which I'm using.

Am I missing another reference?

In case it's relevant, I added this after receiving an error that "cross-thread operation was not valid" using a server/client socket.

Comment: I think you want to ditch the `this.` part of `this.Dispatcher`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Tried; "object reference is required"

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms does not have a `Dispatcher` in it. Use try `this.BeginInvoke(..)`

Comment: Bad question information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WinForms does not have a `Dispatcher` in it.

In order to post asynchronous UI update( that's exactly what `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` does),  just use  `this.BeginInvoke(..)` It's a method from `Control` base class.
In your case you could have something like this (adopted from MSDN [pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

```
private delegate void InvokeDelegate();
private void tbAux_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(HandleSelection));
}
private void HandleSelection()
{
   textBox.Text = tbAux.Text;
}
```

If you want a synchronous update, use `this.Invoke`

Comment: This throws 3 errors; `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments`, `cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority' to 'System.Delegate'` and `cannot convert from 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' to 'object[]'`

Comment: there is no `DispatcherPriority` in windorms. Just pass a delegate. I provided a code example in answer

Comment: the `=>` is throwing an error: `Invalid expression term '=>'`

Comment: Updated it to vanilla .net 2.0 style. which version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: I am working on 4.0. Your latest edit worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) concept belong to WPF technology and you are using Winforms on winforms you can use this or control .Begin or BeginInvoke both of these are similer to Dispatcher.Begin or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Basically both of these are from Delegate class which is getting implemented by CLR for you at runtime.