# Progress dialog on a heavy loaded UI thread does not get updated when binding changes

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding

While maintaining an old MFC application we have implemented a new progress dialog bar in WPF. The application currently has the UI thread busy with a lot of business operations but changing this is out of scope.

When a string property changes its value (binded to the text of a TextBox) the progress dialog does not get refreshed (only sometimes when the thread is not so busy).

As far as I know as the update of the property is done from the UI thread the thread should be able to update the dialog and repaint it before going on the next thing so I don't get why it's not being updated and how to fix it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: What are the drawbacks of this solution, I have tried it and seems to work fine:

```
private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
{
   uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
}
```

Comment: Can and should are not the same.  If I update public string value bound to a TexBlock in a tight loop 1000 times I do not want the UI to hold that up for 1000 refreshes.

Comment: Then how can I notify the window that it should update?

Comment: U have told it is should update.  The problem is by loading up the main thread u are not giving it time.  If you cannot move business tasks off the main thread then WPF is probably not right product for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution here:

http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

Then I created a new thread with the progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> The application currently has the UI thread busy with a lot of business operations

Well there's your problem.  You shouldn't be doing that.  You ought to be performing long running operations in a non-UI thread.  It's the reason why updates to the UI aren't made until after the long running operation finishes.

You can use a `BackgroundWorker` to help simplify interactions with a UI while performing a long running task, as it will handle marshaling to the UI thread for the progress updated and completed event handlers.

Comment: I of course know that but as I said in the question "changing this is out of scope". If I'm doing the changes on the UI thread I don't know why the dialog can not update itself before continuing.

Comment: @SoMoS This is how the problem should be solved.  Most any solution that involves doing work in the UI thread is going to have significant bugs/race conditions, and just generally not work outside of the simple test cases, and any that do work and don't have bugs will be significantly more work than just doing work in a non-UI thread.  If you want to actually solve your problem and not generate dozens more in the process you should take the time to move the work to a non-UI thread.  You're fighting the design of the system to do otherwise.

Comment: This is not a C# application, it's a MFC one with interop with WPF, that's why it's out of the scope changing this (we're talking an app with more than 100.000 code lines). If I could force a refresh on the UI as it was possible with WinForms that would be enougth

Comment: @SoMoS The WPF framework went out of their way to *avoid* providing such a method, specifically for the reasons I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with @Servy, you shouldn't do heavy work in the UI thread.
However, if you cannot do the work in another thread, you can consider spawning another one for your dialog. I don't know how you are calling the wpf window, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381967/show-wpf-window-from-test-unit/13382721#13382721) may give you some clues about how it would be done in C#.