# C# Unit Test open Window.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xaml

I need to open my `Window.xaml` in Unit Test. I tried a simple code as follows:

```
 [Test]
 public void Test_window()
 {
      var mw = new MainWindow();
      mw.Show();
 }
```

The above code ends with an error.

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

Afterwards, I tried the below code :

```
     [Test]
     public void Test_window()
     {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            var mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();
        }));

        th.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        th.Start();

     }
```

In this case , the test passes successfully, but no window is shown. Since I am new to WPF, it would be appreciable if any suggestions or guidance are available here.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you open the window in a unit test in the fist place?

Comment: Usually unit tests are automated without a UI, which is why a lot of people use an MVC or MVVM pattern. The logic is in a separate class that can be unit tested aside from the UI.

Comment: If you want to do automation tests you should use different approach, like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx or Selenium

Comment: Use MVVM, test the ViewModel without the View (your window)

Comment: I am using MVVM, but I would like to show how that window looks with mock data. It would be simple excell-like table without funcionality. Is there a way even if it is not best practices?

Comment: Maybe you should think about coded-ui

Comment: If you just want to *look* at the view with mock data, that's not a unit test at all. I often use fake ViewModels with hard coded data and set them as design-time DataContext in the View.

Comment: Sometimes you need to create a window, for example to get a handle which is necessary to test some methods, especially those using WinAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is shown, but very fast, because you don't wait for the window. You could do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test_window()
{
    var showMonitor = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    var closeMonitor = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        var mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();

        showMonitor.Set();
        closeMonitor.WaitOne();
    }));

    th.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
    th.Start();

    showMonitor.WaitOne();
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    //anything you need to test
    closeMonitor.Set();
}
```

It is possible to achieve the same with only one monitor, but it's more readable in this way.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I had much better luck with this solution where you turn on the message pump: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381967/show-wpf-window-from-test-unit